# How to prevent Windows 8 of erasing GRUB?

Tags: ubuntu, windows-8, boot, grub, uefi

I'm doing dualboot with Ubuntu and Windows 8 on my DELL Laptop. EFI is enabled, secure boot is not. My partitions are GPT.

Everything seems to work for some time. After some normal use, GRUB stops working. The "ubuntu" EFI entry is still there on top of everything else. But the computer boots directly into the Windows Bootloader, skipping GRUB.

Any clues on why is that happening or how can I prevent that?

**My current partiton setup is**:

```
- /dev/sda1    NTFS    Windows recovery
- /dev/sda2    FAT32   UEFI boot (with boot flag)
- /dev/sda3    unknown (msftres flag)
- /dev/sda4    NTFS    Windows Drive C
- /dev/sda5    ext4    /home
- /dev/sda6    ext4    /
```

**I usually reinstall GRUB** through chrooting from a Live Session and doing a `apt-get install --reinstall grub-efi-amd64`.